# Sending email using javamail with if else statement

Tags: java, android, email

I am using the code mentioned here: [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

This is my code. When the user reaches a specific point the mail should be automatically sent but it's not happening. Permissions are perfect.

```
if (User.TOTAL_POINTS >= 2) {
    try { 

        Mail m = new Mail("rubypawa1@gmail.com", "my password"); 

        String[] toArr = {"suvinay123@gmail.com", "rubypawa1@gmail.com.com"}; 
        m.setTo(toArr); 
        m.setFrom("rubypawa1@gmail.com"); 
        m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
        m.setBody("Email body."); 

        if(m.send()) { 
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } else { 
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `rubypawa1@gmail.com.com` (redundant `.com`)? What's happening? Do you see any toast and which? Do you get exception?

Comment: Yeah sorry that .com is not there.And i do not see any toast or error message.So i am unable to figure out whats happening

Comment: Is there an exception in the log? Are you sure that `User.TOTAL_POINTS` is greater or equal 2?